# laravel eloquent relations not working

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

im using laravel 5.4 , i have a brand table and a products table and my relations are this :

```
class Product extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'products';


  public function brand()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
  }
}
```

And

```
class Brand extends Model
{

  public function products()
  {
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
  }
}
```

My Migrations :

```
    Schema::create('brands', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name',15)->unique();
        $table->string('tag',15)->unique();
        $table->mediumInteger('numofads')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

&

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('brand_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name',15)->unique();
        $table->string('tag',15)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->mediumInteger('numofads')->unsigned()->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

in my Controller i will take 3 brand and send them to the view :

```
public function show()
{
   $brands = Brand::take(3)->get();

   return view('show',compact('brands'));
}
```

And in my view i will iterate that to show just products like this:

```
@foreach($brands as $brand)
   {{ $brand->products->name }}
@endforeach
```

I think everything i ok but i will get error :

```
ErrorException in Collection.php line 1543:
Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/k1/Laravel/carsan/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$brand->products` is going to be a `Collection`. You will have to iterate that. It is not a single model, it potentially contains many models, just like `$brands` is a collection of models.

```
@foreach ($brands as $brand)
    ...
    @foreach ($brand->products as $product)
        ...
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: oh it worked and thanks alot . but i saw a video that did it like this : {{ $brand->products->name }} and it worked!!!!

Comment: Probably they were using older laravel version in that video. 
Return type of that was changed not so long time ago. 
That is one of the reasons people hate laravel

Comment: @matiit but they are using 5.4.16 and im sure

Comment: @matiit the dynamic property for relationships that are many (hasMany, belongsToMany, etc.) has returned a collection for many years. What are you referring to in regards to Eloquent here that has changed not so long time ago?

Comment: @lagbox My mistake, I was referring to https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/10478